# LED bulb dims and flickers when turned up to max position on sliding dimmer switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch

Older house(1973).  Hanging ceiling light fixture in den has dimmer switch and light would flicker periodically.  During renovations I installed new LED dimmer switch and put in new dimmable LED bulb.  Flickering seems to have stopped except when dimmer slider on switch is raised to max position the bulb dims and flickers.  Everything is fine up to about 75% power on switch.  Thanks for the help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am in NZ. My experience has been that the dimmer flashes when on solar power which is at 240V. Whereas supply is at 220V. It was also causing premature failure. So I  ended up replacing the dimmer with a switch and everything works fine. I  had to do that on all 8 such circuits.  So try testing with a switch without a dimmer.

Comment: Dimming on LEDs is a black art.  The LEDs are hit and miss and so are the dimmers. Old legacy "non-LED-rated" dimmers even more so.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact problem. I wound up using a different brand of dimmer switch. First I would try a different brand of light bulb. When it comes to LED components quality matters.